spidermonkey has a version jsshell, i want to print trace gc like node?
By using the node to run a js file ,it is easy to print gc information such as GC time ,memory...
node --trace-gc xx.js

I want to ask spidermonkey to print gc information. Is there an easy way like node?
I looked at the spidermonkey documentation and found that it was impossible to achieve my goals from the command line.
